# JTable обновление при добавлении строки

Tags: jtable, java

Покажите пожалуйста простейший вариант таблицы (JTable) с кнопкой, при нажатии на кнопку в таблицу должна добавляться одна строка с произвольными данными(можно и пустые), заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавлять надо не в JTable а в модель.
соответственно у модели данные храни в ArrayList или Vector и опиши метод addElement

Comment: +1, только использовать вектор уже не тру